# Split a List into several Lists based on sum of List in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
list_ = [30.3125, 13.75, 12.1875, 30.625, 18.125, 58.75, 38.125, 33.125, 55.3125, 28.75, 60.3125, 31.5625, 59.0625]
total = 150.0
new_list = []

while sum(list_) > total:
    new_list.append(list_[-1:])
    list_ = list_[:-1]

new_list.reverse()

print(list_)
>>> [30.3125, 13.75, 12.1875, 30.625, 18.125]
print(new_list)
>>> [58.75, 38.125, 33.125, 55.3125, 28.75, 60.3125, 31.5625, 59.0625]
```

My question is I want to repeat the code for the new_list just created, but I don't know how.( I want it automatically split the list when the sum of the values in a list greater than total.)

I want the result like this.

```
>>> list_     = [30.3125, 13.75, 12.1875, 30.625, 18.125]
>>> new_list  = [58.75, 38.125, 33.125]
>>> new_list1 = [55.3125, 28.75, 60.3125]
>>> new_list2 = [31.5625, 59.0625]
```

Thanks all.

Comment: maybe a list of lists could be the best choice for you.

Comment: Why `list_[-1:][0]` instead of `list_[-1]`?

Comment: @ Veltro: Could you please so kind explain how to use list of lists?

Comment: @ettanany because in my code it returns a list of lists like this [[31.5625]] for each item added to a new list.

Comment: But `list_[-1:][0]` and `list_[-1]` return the same single value

Comment: @ettanany maybe something is wrong somewhere in my code, I will check. Just edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting them in a dictionary?

```
list_ = [30.3125, 13.75, 12.1875, 30.625, 18.125, 58.75, 38.125, 33.125, 55.3125, 28.75, 60.3125, 31.5625, 59.0625]
total = 150.0

dict_ = {}

sum_ = 0
i = 0

for item in list_:    
    # When sum + item > total reset sum and go to next key
    sum_ += item
    if sum_ + item > total:
        sum_ = 0
        i+= 1
    dict_.setdefault(i, []).append(item)

dict_
```

Prints

```
 {0: [30.3125, 13.75, 12.1875, 30.625, 18.125],
 1: [58.75, 38.125, 33.125],
 2: [55.3125, 28.75, 60.3125],
 3: [31.5625, 59.0625]}
```

And if you badly want the assignments you can do:

```
for key,value in dict_.items():
    if key == 0:
        exec("list_={}".format(str(value)))
    elif key == 1:
        exec("new_list={}".format(str(value)))
    else:
        exec("new_list{}={}".format(str(key-1),str(value)))

list_
```

Prints

```
[30.3125, 13.75, 12.1875, 30.625, 18.125]
```

Comment: That is so great. But the sum at 1 is greater than 150 ( the sum is 185.3125). Do you know why?

Comment: @ryanvolap oh yes, it keeps adding values while it is lower than 150, I can fix that

Comment: @ryanvolap fixed it.  **if sum_ + item > total:** now  (looks at the current item + old sum)

Comment: Thank you thank you so much. I love your solution. That's exactly what I need. I thought about dictionary but I didn't know how. I'm learning a new trick from you. Much appreciated...

Comment: @ryanvolap No worries, glad I could help. I would not recommend using the exec() functions however. In most cases these are not necessary and dictionaries alone do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the code from the solution above, and creating 'splits' and 'sums' of the sublists.  I'm getting sums of sublists that are exceeding the 'max'.  But I'm new to programming so it's a challenge to troubleshoot.

Specifically, the 4th list is totaling as 42079.94, which is greater than 'max' of 40000.

My list is quite long:

```
rounded = ['2173.46', '5160.07', '4967.87', '4956.85', '5368.52', '5416.99', '5769.32', '5416.99', '6168.42', '5416.99', '2551.58', '3968.48', '5416.99', '6970.02', '5416.99', '7370.98', '5416.99', '7774.94', '5368.75', '8093.52', '5802.37', '5651.04', '5789.39', '5638.3', '5789.39', '5315.93', '5789.39', '5253.33', '5782.12', '5253.33', '5810.41', '5253.33', '5900.1', '5253.33', '5900.1', '5253.33', '5815.67', '5253.33', '5788.27', '5253.33', '5912.87', '5366.49', '6830.97', '6841.2', '6385.11', '6163.01', '6419.96', '6836.72', '5886.96', '1809.82', '2060.69', '2495.1', '2495.62', '6767.83', '6836.72', '2309.49', '1075.67', '1075.67', '2061.71', '1075.67', '1075.67']
```

```
dict_ = {}

sum_ = 0
i = 0
max = 40000

for item in rounded:    
    # When sum + item > max reset sum and go to next key
    sum_ += item
    if sum_ + item > max:
        sum_ = 0
        i+= 1
    dict_.setdefault(i, []).append(item)

splits = []
for i in range(0,len(dict_)):
    splits.append(len(dict_[i]))

sums = []
for i in range(0,len(dict_)):
    sums.append(sum(dict_[i]))

print sums
```

```
sums = ['33813.08', '35909.47', '31348.65', '**42079.94**', '39042.01', '38517.36', '37499.65', '34772.7', '15510.6']
```